# Dropbox uploading within script

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I have a form that allows a user to fill in several aspects and then choose a file to upload.

When the form is submitted, I want write some code that saves the file to a dropbox account and gets access to a direct download link and places this in a database I am hosting.

If anyone has done this, is there a specific section of the API to look at? Or any examples?

I can't seem to find this in the API.

Thanks.

Comment: did you manage to solve your problem with any of the answers below? If so, please take a moment to upvote and accept the answer you find best. :)

Answer (score 17):

From what I see in the API it is possible to do this. You need to download the [Dropbox Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/php). Inside the zip file, you will find an example folder with example code for authentication, upload, download, direct-link and so on. Just see the `direct-link.php` and change it to your needs. Here is a tested working example of uploading a file and generating a direct link for download:

```
<?php

require_once "dropbox-php-sdk-1.1.2/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php";

use \Dropbox as dbx;

$dropbox_config = array(
    'key'    => 'your_key',
    'secret' => 'your_secret'
);

$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJson($dropbox_config);
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");

$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();
echo "1. Go to: " . $authorizeUrl . "<br>";
echo "2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first).<br>";
echo "3. Copy the authorization code and insert it into $authCode.<br>";

$authCode = trim('DjsR-iGv4PAAAAAAAAAAAbn9snrWyk9Sqrr2vsdAOm0');

list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
echo "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "<br>";

$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");

// Uploading the file
$f = fopen("working-draft.txt", "rb");
$result = $dbxClient->uploadFile("/working-draft.txt", dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($result);

// Get file info
$file = $dbxClient->getMetadata('/working-draft.txt');

// sending the direct link:
$dropboxPath = $file['path'];
$pathError = dbx\Path::findError($dropboxPath);
if ($pathError !== null) {
    fwrite(STDERR, "Invalid <dropbox-path>: $pathError\n");
    die;
}

// The $link is an array!
$link = $dbxClient->createTemporaryDirectLink($dropboxPath);
// adding ?dl=1 to the link will force the file to be downloaded by the client.
$dw_link = $link[0]."?dl=1";

echo "Download link: ".$dw_link."<br>";

?>
```

I made this really fast just to get it working. Eventually you may need to tweak it a bit so it will suite your needs.

Comment: how/where to get $authCode?

Comment: As far as I remember, that was generated when you go through the authorization process. The example I've posted combines the `examples/authorize.php`, `examples/upload-file.php` and `examples/direct-link.php`. You should go through them to better understand how the API works.

Comment: So After I clicked the the link, it gave me this message saying "Enter this code into myApps to finish the process. Where do i exactly put this if im working from a website?

Comment: I don't remember any more. Probably when you go to `$authorizeUrl` in your browser, it will give you an authentication code. You should copy that code in `$authCode` and open the url to the php script.

Answer (score 1):

There is section in the Core API manual, see [this](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php#uploading) link.
So you can use the upload part like this:

```
$f = file_get_contents('data.txt');
$result = $dbxClient->uploadFile("/data.txt", dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);

echo 'file uploaded';
```