# Dropbox file upload automatically using php

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I'm playing with Dropbox API for PHP, and I would like know the correct way to upload files automatically without command line.

Now my process is:

1. `php -f upload.php`
2. Copy long url on browser
3. Click allow button
4. Copy the token
5. paste the token on console and done.

My plan is do an *automated backup* of some JSON files on my Dropbox.

Is there other way to make that without console? and copying tokens and simple solution?

**EDIT**
When I try to hardcode it, the output it´s ->

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Dropbox\Exception_BadRequest' with message 'HTTP status 400
{"error_description": "code has already been used", "error": "invalid_grant"}'
```

**EDIT 2***

The access token output

```
dusIlAq36pkAAAAAAAAHQ6daX9hwt-3wUL240gUUjIOYrscX2OYOkCyj8ZghUgG2
```

I set it as

```
$authCode = 'dusIlAq36pkAAAABBBBBAAAHQ6daX9hwt-3wUL240gUUjIOYrscX2OYOkCyj8ZghUgG2';
```

Here Drop MSG

```
 ...Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Dropbox\Exception_BadRequest' with message 'HTTP status 400
{"error_description": "code doesn't exist or has expired",
```

Comment: from this SO link answer you may get your desired answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078934/dropbox-uploading-within-script?rq=1

Comment: I have updated the question I can´t hardcode it says this code was alreay used. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user only has to authorize your app once. After that, you can just keep reusing that access token. (You can hardcode it in your script.)

**EDIT**

From https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php:

> Finally, call finish to convert the authorization code into an access
>   token.
>
> ```
> list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
> print "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n";
> ```
>
> The access token is all you'll need to make API requests on behalf of
>   this user, so you should store it away for safe-keeping (even though
>   we don't for this tutorial). By storing the access token, you won't
>   need to go through these steps again unless the user reinstalls your
>   app or revokes access via the Dropbox website.

Comment: Hi Smarx, I tried that but I get this error, I have updated my question, thanks for your reply.

Comment: It sounds from your edit like you're trying to reuse an authorization code instead of the access token. See my edit.

Comment: Hi Smarx I tried but see my edit please, and thanks for your reply.

Comment: Now it looks like you're saving the access code but trying to use it as an authorization code.

Answer (score 0):

you are using access token as authcode - you muset set it as $accessToken

```
$accessToken = 'dusIlAq36pkAAAABBBBBAAAHQ6daX9hwt-3wUL240gUUjIOYrscX2OYOkCyj8ZghUgG2';
```

and comment whole authcode process. You do not need it when you have access token.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: "This access token can be used to access your account (you@example.com) via the API. Don’t share your access token with anyone."